# Datatables - Table hide column and order

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have a bootstrap table, with six columns but I only show 5 columns !

I put an hidden column with `<td class="d-none">`

I try to order the table with some Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "order": [ 0, 'desc' ]
        } );
    });
```

But this JS code don't work anymore, because of the hidden column, How can I order my table ? And add the "show 100 entries" and "Search" ?

[image]

Comment: This is `datatable` not `bootstrap  table`. Don't hide table column with `css` use datatable configuration to do that refer https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

Comment: It is just dom representation. Better include more snippets and convey what issue are you facing?

Comment: Oh nice ! Thank you :)
I didn't saw your edit, this link is the perfect answer for my problem !

Comment: I'm glad to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry for this second question, but I don't find any answer, maybe you can help me ! 
I try to get the value of "td" which is hidden in my table with JS code : `var $chro = $rw.find("td:nth-child(2)");`
This line is supposed to get the value of the second "td", but insted of getting the hidden td value, it give me the third td value :/
Do you know a solution to get hidden td ?

Comment: Try to get entire row data so that you will get the hidden informations too.

Comment: Not realy, I tried something like this to get all row :
`var $rw = $(this).closest("tr");
   
      var tableData = $rw.children("td").map(function() {
          return $rw.text();
      }).get();`


I can see all data except the hidden column

(I use this to hide the second column)
`$('#myTable').DataTable( {
   "order": [ 0, 'desc' ],
         "columnDefs": [
             {
                 "targets": [ 1 ],
                 "visible": false,
                 "searchable": false
             }
         ]
     } );`

Maybe an idea ?

Comment: You are still using pure javascript. Please refer datatable api  docs to access data from datatables.